# FlaskApp and Website running on the same ubuntu server

Tags: python, apache, amazon-ec2, flask, mod-wsgi

I am working on an Ubuntu EC2 server. I have a website hosted here. For a mobile application i was suggested to use an api to send or receive data in JSON format.
I could find multiple solutions in the internet. Which has got me confused.

Kindly clarify the below questions.

How do i run the flask app and a website from the same server?
The solution i used seems to disable my website and gives me error 500.
https://www.datasciencebytes.com/bytes/2015/02/24/running-a-flask-app-on-aws-ec2/

How can i reconfigure my server to specifically respond for mobile devices?
What should be the server set up 
The current setup i used in the sites-enabled is as below

```
    WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi

    <Directory flaskapp>
     WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
     WSGIApplicationGroup %{RESOURCE}
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
     </Directory>
```

What would be the change necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either mount the Flask app at a sub URL, eg:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /suburl /var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi
```

or do some trickery to have only requests that don't match static files passed through to the WSGI application, see explanation towards end of this section of documentation.

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/configuration-guidelines.html#the-apache-alias-directive

Also, don't use:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{RESOURCE}
```

use:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

And:

```
<Directory flaskapp>
```

should be:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/flaskapp>
```

Finally, don't forget to set the Python module search path somehow so your application code can be found. See:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html